# How to pass a pytest test that is waiting for an event?

Tags: python, pytest, eventemitter

I wrote an EventEmitter package that works fine between different modules on its own. However, when trying to listen for an event in a pytest test, I can't get the listener to fire without `mock.Mock()`. However, this doesn't return the received message, which makes sense, because I'm passing the mocked function which then becomes `message`. How can I get this pytest test to pass?

```py
def received(message):
    print(message)
    return message


def test_pubsub_listen():
    pubsub.listen(subscription_id, 5)

    func = mock.Mock()

    events.on("subscription_id", received(func))

    func.assert_called_with("expected message")
```

This is the `pubsub.listen` method code, which is part of a larger class for Google Cloud Platform.

```py
    def listen(self, subscription_id, timeout):
        subscriber = self.subscriber

        subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_id)

        def stream(message: pubsub_v1.subscriber.message.Message) -> None:
            events.emit("subscription_id", message)
            message.ack

            return message

        streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(subscription_path, callback=stream)

        if timeout == 0:
            while True:
                streaming_pull_future.result()
        else:
            # with subscriber:
            try:
                streaming_pull_future.result(timeout=timeout)
            except TimeoutError:
                streaming_pull_future.cancel()
                streaming_pull_future.result()
                pass
```

Comment: `received` doesn't call its argument on anything.

Comment: @chepner Right - because I don't understand what to do..

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Is `received` the thing you are trying to test? Or is `pubsub` the thing you are trying to test, to ensure that `received` gets called?

Comment: I am emitting messages from within `pubsub.listen` using the EventEmitter I wrote. I am trying to test that the correct message is received by the listener. Outside of pytest, everything works fine with the receive function. It looks like this `events.on("subscription_id", received)`. But I don't know how to tell pytest to wait for `received`'s message and assert that it is what is expected.

Comment: The only way I could get the listener to fire at all inside the test was by passing `func` into received, which is most certainly not the right way to get the message back to pytest.

Comment: How does the `EventEmitter` get used? That seems to be missing from your test.

Comment: Right now, the pubsub system isn't doing anything; you are *explicitly* calling `received`, to the output you see happens before `event.on` is even called.

Comment: I added the code for the `listen` method from a larger class for GCP

Comment: I'm not sure `listen` is really relevant. It's listening for an event, sure, but you need to *send* an event for it to "hear". Mocking `received` is just a proxy for confirming that it received the event sent by your emitter. Depending on how, exactly, that works, it might be better to mock the entire pubsub with somethign that can simply report that yes, it received an event from your emitter.

Comment: Yes. I have that happening in another test and I know it is working because I can print the message directly in the `pubsub.listen` method of the larger class. And i know that my `events.on` method is working, because ==> outside of the pytest test, it works just fine. The problem is only happening inside of pytest, where the listener won't fire unless I pass a value into `receive`. But I also have the problem of understanding how to return the message `receive` gets back to pytest.

Comment: Got it working! As I believe you pointed out, I should be listening with my `events.listen` **before** I call `pubsub.listen`. No need for `mock.Mock()` Thank you for bearing with me.